# How do I find an integer from this?

Tags: vector-spaces

I am working with Iris dataset as part of math in data science class.

So I have made the feature dataframe with the 4 columns, each representing a different measurement of the flower (i.e. 4.3cm sepal width)

So if these features can be seen as a matrix whose rows are point in the vector space $R^n$, what integer is $n$ in $R^n$?

Is it just 4 for the 4 columns?

Does the term $R^n$ just mean 4-dimensional space?

Thanks

Comment: The design matrix $X$ has shape $150 \times 4$ before any train/test example split. $150$ corresponds to the number of instances (observations) and $4$ corresponds to the number of features (attributes).

Comment: In general, an $m \times n$ matrix is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, which is essentially the same thing as $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$.

Comment: @William an $m \times n$ design matrix is a vector in $M_{m \times n} (\mathbb{R})$ (the space of $m \times n$ matrices with real entries), which is isomorphic to either of the vector spaces in your comment.